# A lot of different errors while trying to use Axios in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, axios

So I want to use axios, and so within my project I first npm init, then npm i axios --save

I then used const axios = require("axios"); but an error popped up saying "require is not defined". I am already running the app in a node environment

I read online saying I should use import. No worries. So I did import axios from "axios"; out came an error saying "import declarations may only appear at the top of the module"
Apparently that's because the script isn't a module. From the HTML file I added type="module" to the index.js script. It said module specifiers must start with ./, ../ or /

so I added import axios from "/axios", but it said "loading module from http://localhost/axios was blocked because of a disallowed mime type"

and at this point I have no clue what I can do, and the only way I can use axios is through the unpkg link which I put into my html file. But I want to use axios through import.
Do anyone of you have more solutions to this?

Comment: can you share your code please

Comment: have you tried `import axios from "/axios.js"`

Comment: Sorry it /axios.js didn't work. It showed: Loading module from “http://localhost:63342/axios.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”). and Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:63342/axios.js”. It also shows: GEThttp://localhost:63342/axios.js 404 not found

Comment: `MIME type (“text/html”).` your server is either sending wrong mime type or the file doesn't exist at `/axios.js` - check the browser developer console - is there a 404 error when trying to load /axios.js?

Comment: Yes, there's a 404 while trying to GET axios

Comment: well, your path is wrong ... try `./axios.js` if axios.js is in the same folder as the web page ... otherwise, try the correct path in relation to where the html file is (or maybe relative to the index.js ... I think modules do things differently) anyway ... the path needs to be correct, of course

Comment: Do I need to specify axios.js within node_modules within the path? All my axios stuff is inside that folder. My project literally has a very simple structure: An HTML file, a JS file and node_modules and package.json. I'm not sure what my path to axios.js will be

Comment: Although you do use NPM you're not running anything in a node environment, but in the browser. The browser knows nothing about *resolving import paths* so you will have to use an absolute path to point to the file. Nowadays you can use a build tool, like Parcel or Webpack to construct a single JS file from all your imports **with** the ability to resolve a path like `import axios from 'axios'`. I would suggest that you explore these tools. They can be a pain to setup, but once running you can enjoy their powerful features.

Comment: How do I do that? Why don't they ever mention using Webpack or Parcel in any youtube videos or text tutorials? All the tutorials seem to just do npm i axios then import and boom everything's working, but for me nothing works